# UIButton title label font weight is not changing to BOLD inside custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView Subclass

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In my program I want to apply bold system font to UIButton's titleLabel inside custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView Subclass. But everytime font with regular weight showing.

**NOTE HINT: FOR UIBUTTON, I CREATED UIBUTTON's SUBCLASS (NAMED AS BUTTON, FOR AUTO ADJUST FONT SIZE TO FIT UIBUTTON's FRAME HEIGHT). WHEN I USE UIBUTTON IN PLACE OF BUTTON, BOLD FONT GETS APPLIED PROPERLY. JUST LIKE**

```
private let createVmButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0x0083C5, alpha: 1)
        button.setTitle("Create VM", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25, weight: UIFontWeightBold)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()
```

**COMPLETE PROGRAM:
UIButton SUBCLASS:**

```
class Button: UIButton {

    var fontSize: CGFloat = 0
    var frameHeight: CGFloat = 0

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if let titleLabel = titleLabel {
            titleLabel.font = titleLabel.font.withSize(frame.size.height * (fontSize / frameHeight))
        }
    }
}
```

**UITableViewHeaderFooterView SUBCLASS:**

```
class VmListFooter: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    private let createVmButton: Button = {
        let button = Button(type: .system)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0x0083C5, alpha: 1)
        button.setTitle("Create VM", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25, weight: UIFontWeightBold)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.fontSize = 25
        button.frameHeight = 60
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()

    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0xF1F1F1, alpha: 1)
        setUpViews()
        createVmButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onCreateVmPressed(sender: )), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func onCreateVmPressed(sender: Button) {
        print("VM Create Button Pressed")
    }

    private func setUpViews() {
        contentView.addSubview(createVmButton)

        // x, y, width, height => createVmButton
        contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: createVmButton,
            attribute: .centerX,
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: contentView,
            attribute: .centerX,
            multiplier: 1,
            constant: 0
        ))
        contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: createVmButton,
            attribute: .centerY,
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: contentView,
            attribute: .centerY,
            multiplier: 1,
            constant: 0
        ))
        contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: createVmButton,
            attribute: .width,
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: contentView,
            attribute: .width,
            multiplier: (374.0 / 414.0),
            constant: 0
        ))
        createVmButton.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: createVmButton,
            attribute: .height,
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: createVmButton,
            attribute: .width,
            multiplier: (60.0 / 374.0),
            constant: 0
        ))  // aspect ratio

        contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
class Button: UIButton {

    var fontSize: CGFloat = 0
    var frameHeight: CGFloat = 0

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: frame.size.height * (fontSize / frameHeight))
    }
}


private let createVmButton: Button = {
        let button = Button(type: .system)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0x0083C5, alpha: 1)
        button.setTitle("Create VM", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.fontSize = 30
        button.frameHeight = 60
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but In my program, I have other places also where I have used this "Button" class. If I apply BOLD fontweight forcefully here, that will be reflected to other code also

Comment: @Sanket So I think your code will work too. I have tried your code on my simulator and it work!

Comment: Yes my code is working everywhere except in this UITableViewHeaderFooterView subclass. I don't know what is the problem. I have tested the result on my IPHONE DEVICE. There I came across this issue.